# What cast occurs when there is a signed/unsigned mismatch?

Tags: c++, casting, warnings

When a compiler finds a signed / unsigned mismatch, what action does it take? Is the signed number cast to an unsigned or vice versa? and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If operand are integral and there is an unsigned value, then conversion to unsigned is done. For example:

```
-1 > (unsigned int)1 // as -1 will be converted to 2^nbits-1
```

Conversion int->unsigned int is: n>=0 -> n; n<0 -> n (mod 2^nbits), for example -1 goes to 2^nbits-1

Conversion unsigned int->int is: n <= INT_MAX -> n; n > INT_MAX -> implementation defined

> If the destination type is unsigned,
>   the resulting value is the least
>   unsigned integer congruent to the
>   source integer (modulo 2^n where n is
>   the number of bits used to represent
>   the unsigned type).
>
> If the destination type is signed, the
>   value is unchanged if it can be
>   represented in the destination type
>   (and bit-field width); otherwise, the
>   value is implementation-defined.

Comment: As for, "and why?": the standard covers "usual arithmetic conversions" in 5:9. If the only difference between the types of the operands in that one is unsigned, then with a bit of head-scratching, the 4th, 5th and 8th rules in the list together imply what you say.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think C++ deviates from the way C handles signed/unsigned conversions:

> Conversion rules are more complicated
>   when `unsigned` operands are involved.
>   The problem is that comparisons
>   between signed and unsigned values are
>   machine-dependent, because they depend
>   on the sizes of the various integer
>   types. (K&R)

One important factor to consider is whether one of the types is a `long` integer or not, because that will affect integer promotions. For example, if a `long int` is compared to an `unsigned int`, and a `long int` can represent all the values of an `unsigned int`, then the `unsigned int` will be converted to a `long int`. (Otherwise, they're both just converted to an `unsigned long int`.)

In most cases, though, the compiler should convert signed integers to unsigned integers if it finds a mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

It could be compiler-specific.
If you look at the Question "[Should I disable the C compiler signed/unsigned mismatch warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515803/should-i-disable-the-c-compiler-signed-unsigned-mismatch-warning)" you see that in case of "litb" the variable the signed-var got "promoted" to an unsigned value.

In any case there is no "correct" way for a compiler to handle this situation once one variable reaches a certain value (that is, where the [most significant bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit) is set).
So, if you have such a warning, be sure to get rid of it ;)